# How can I distinguish between editing and creating a new item in my validation method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to ensure that each item in my cms has a unique url.

The model has been made an IValidatableObject and I am using the validation method below.

The trouble I'm having is discerning whether the item is being created (url must not match any existing items) or edited (url must not match any item *other than itself*).

How can I do this... and am I even approaching this the right way?

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        string itemContainingURL = db.CMSPages.Where(c => c.URL == URL).Select(c => c.Title).SingleOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemContainingURL))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(String.Format("URL should be unique, but it already exists for item: {0}", itemContainingURL), new[] { "URL" });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it matter? Just test existence of an item *of differing ID* that shares the URL, and you can cover both cases.

Example pseudocode:

```
bool IsUnique()
{
    return !repository.Any(x => x.ID != this.ID && x.URL == this.URL);
}
```

Comment: Of course, that's the second daft question I've asked today. :-$  Thank you

Comment: No problem. It's a good question anyway, and sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes.